# Solving: $\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}u_y+(3y\cos2x)u=2x^2y\cot2x.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can' t solve the following linear PDE, since it includes trigonometric functions by the characteristic method. $$\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}u_y+(3y\cos2x)u=2x^2y\cot2x.$$
Could you help me, please?

Comment: The trigonometric functions are all in $x$, while your partial derivative is wrt $y$...

Comment: Oh, then it is an linear ODE. But I think it is still a difficult question at least for me. I found integral factor $-\frac{3 \sqrt{x \left(3 x+y^2\right)}\cos(2x) }{x}$ Could you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We change the variable $y$ to $t$ with substitution $\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}=t$ so
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}}$$
then
$$\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}u_y=y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$
and
$$
\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}u_y+(3y\cos2x)u=2x^2y\cot2x.
$$
will be
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+(3\cos2x)u=2x^2\cot2x$$
this first order equation solved with integration factor $I=e^{3\cos2xdt}=e^{3t\cos2x}$ therefore
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{3t\cos2x}u\right)=2x^2\cot2xe^{3t\cos2x}$$
gives us
$$u=\dfrac{2x^2}{3\sin2x}+C(t)e^{-3t\cos2x}$$
and finally
$$\color{blue}{u=\dfrac{2x^2}{3\sin2x}+C(x,y)e^{-3\cos2x\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}}}$$

Comment: I have two questions related to your solution. First, after substituting $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}= y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, every time will $y$ be canceled and will unknown function $u$ be depend on one variable? If it wasn' t canceled, how will we solve? Second; how will we deduce that integral constant $C$  depends on both $x$ and $y$? Thanks for your solution.

Comment: For the first, I don't know what you said (sorry), it's better to refer calculus books. For the second we found $C(t)$ and deduced from $t(x,y)$ the constant depend on both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: For the first, we substituted $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}= y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ to the main dif. equation, and we got the equation $
\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}u_y+(3y\cos2x)u=2x^2y\cot2x
$ which include independent variables $x, t$. If the equation includes $y$ as well as $x,t$ what will we do?

Comment: Substitution is $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}= \dfrac{y}{t}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ not $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}= y\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. This equation has construction that after substitution, $y$ will be disappear. If after substitution remains some $y$, we couldn't use this way!

Comment: It is exactly what I mean :) Thank you...

Comment: You'r welcome.!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}\frac{du}{dy}+3y\cos(2x)u=2x^2y\cot(2x).$$
HINT : This is a first order linear non-homogeneous ODE where the unknown function is $u(y)$. One can consider $x$ as a parameter since there is no differential wrt $x$.

$\begin{cases}
a=3x^2\\
b=3\cos(2x)\\
c=2x^2\cot(2x)
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad \sqrt{a+y^2}\:\frac{du}{dy}+b\:y\:u(y)=c\:y$

I suppose that you know the method of solving.
$$u(y)=\frac{c}{b}+C\exp\left(-b\sqrt{a+y^2} \right)$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant wrt $y$.
$$u(x,y)=\frac{2x^2\cot(2x)}{3\cos(2x)}+C(x)\exp\left(-3\cos(2x)\sqrt{3x^2+y^2}\right)$$ 
$C(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$.